# Identifying the call that is connected to me via transfer Tapi3

Tags: c#, pbx, tapi

I have been able to create an application that (ab)uses TAPI3Lib and understands incoming calls, puts them on hold, rings an internal number, connects the line that is on hold with the target number.

Below is the code getting the caller number

```
     private void tapi_ITTAPIEventNotification_Event_Event(TAPI3Lib.TAPI_EVENT TapiEvent, object pEvent)
     {
        try
        {

            switch (TapiEvent)
            {
                case TAPI3Lib.TAPI_EVENT.TE_CALLNOTIFICATION:
                    TAPI3Lib.ITCallNotificationEvent cln = pEvent as TAPI3Lib.ITCallNotificationEvent;
                    if (cln.Call.CallState == TAPI3Lib.CALL_STATE.CS_OFFERING)
                    {
                        string c = cln.Call.get_CallInfoString(TAPI3Lib.CALLINFO_STRING.CIS_CALLERIDNUMBER);
                        string target = cln.Call.Address.DialableAddress;
                    .
                    .
                    .
```

Here i run a MSSQL query to a database to identify who is the owner of the number. and i display a form on screen with the potential user that is calling. A button on the form allows you to ring internal numbers (this action automatically adds the current line on hold.

```
    IEnumCall ec = ia[line].EnumerateCalls();
        uint arg = 0;
        ITCallInfo ici;

        try
        {
            ec.Next(1, out ici, ref arg);
            ITBasicCallControl bc = (ITBasicCallControl)ici;
            bc.Hold(true);

        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("May not have any call to put on hold!\n\n" + exp.ToString(), "TAPI3");
        }

        IEnumCall ec1 = ia[line].EnumerateCalls();
        uint arg1 = 0;
        ITCallInfo ici1;

        try
        {
            ec1.Next(1, out ici1, ref arg1);
            ITBasicCallControl bc1 = ia[line].CreateCall("107",TapiConstants.LINEADDRESSTYPE_IPADDRESS, TapiConstants.TAPIMEDIATYPE_AUDIO);
            bc1.Connect(false);


        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Target looks unreachable!\n\n" + exp.ToString(), "TAPI3");
        }
```

This part connects the current active line with the line on hold;

```
    ITBasicCallControl callOnHold = null;
        ITBasicCallControl callConnected = null;
        IEnumCall enumCall = ia[line].EnumerateCalls();
        ITCallInfo callInfo;
        uint dummy = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            enumCall.Next(1, out callInfo, ref dummy);
            if (callInfo == null)
                return;
            if (callInfo.CallState == CALL_STATE.CS_HOLD)
                callOnHold = (ITBasicCallControl)callInfo;
            else if (callInfo.CallState == CALL_STATE.CS_CONNECTED)
                callConnected = (ITBasicCallControl)callInfo;
            if (callOnHold != null && callConnected != null)
                break;
        }

        callOnHold.Transfer(callConnected, true); 
        callConnected.Finish(FINISH_MODE.FM_ASTRANSFER);
```

The initiation is as follows;

```
    ITAddress[] ia = new TAPI3Lib.ITAddress[10]; 
    ...
    try
        {
            tobj = new TAPIClass();
            tobj.Initialize();
            IEnumAddress ea = tobj.EnumerateAddresses();
            ITAddress ln;
            uint arg3 = 0;
            lines = 0;

            cn = new callnotification();

            tobj.ITTAPIEventNotification_Event_Event += new TAPI3Lib.ITTAPIEventNotification_EventEventHandler(cn.Event);
            tobj.EventFilter = (int)(TAPI_EVENT.TE_CALLNOTIFICATION |
                TAPI_EVENT.TE_DIGITEVENT |
                TAPI_EVENT.TE_PHONEEVENT |
                TAPI_EVENT.TE_CALLSTATE |
                TAPI_EVENT.TE_GENERATEEVENT |
                TAPI_EVENT.TE_GATHERDIGITS |
                TAPI_EVENT.TE_REQUEST);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                ea.Next(1, out ln, ref arg3);
                ia[i] = ln;
                if (ln != null)
                {
                   lines++;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
```

--Scenario

**CallA**: Incoming Call

**CallB**: Internal Call

**Operator**: The main answering operator

**Bob**: A user of this application

**Alice**: The caller of CallA

**Bob** uses his cellphone to call **Alice**'s call center. The **Operator** sees a pop-up screen containing **Bob**'s name and number and then picks up the phone. (**CallA** is stored). **Bob** requests to talk to **Alice**. The **Operator** clicks on "**Alice**" on the screen (**CallA** is now on Hold and the **Operator**'s phone creates **CallB** which rings **Alice**'s phone). **Alice** answers the line and agrees to take the call. The **Operator** clicks "Transfer" on screen and **CallA** and **CallB** are connected.

--End of Scenario

--Expected result

When the **Operator** calls **Alice**, the event sees that 100 called 107 (with 100 being the **Operator**'s address on the PBX and 107 **Alice**'s. When the **Operator** connects the 2 calls, I want to be able to pop-up the same screen that the **Operator** got that includes the information of the connected caller. What am i missing in order to fire that event? Because when i try to check the `cln.Call.get_CallInfoString(TAPI3Lib.CALLINFO_STRING.CIS_CALLERIDNUMBER)` all i see is 100 which is the **Operator** that called **Alice** and that is correct. What is the check i need to do in order to identify that a call has been transferred thus → get the caller ID → pop up the screen

--End of Expected result

I wish i was able to describe it as i have it mind.  Thank you for your time and excuse me for the lengthy post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TAPI3 lib may have a bit different naming but the fields you are looking for are called ConnectedId, RedirectingId and RedirectionId on TAPI itself.
But it is very dependent on the PBX itself whether these fields get filled or not.

In a transfered call scenario "theoretically" you should see this in the call information:

- caller id: source of the original call (= the customer)
- called id: destination of the original call (= the published number of the company or service)
- connected id: the actual current other party (= who you are speaking with)
- redirecting id: the number that transferred the call to you (= operator extension)
- redirection id: the number the redirecting party (= operator) transferred the call to, which "should" be the device you are observing this from (if no further forwarding was involved)

But none of this enforced by TAPI so a PBX can fill in what it wants, and different vendors will :(

Comment: The problem is, when i am receiving a call, from the operator, the REDIRECTIONID is null because the line was not redirected to me yet. If i add a break point after i answer the operator's call and let the line get transfered, REDIRECTIONID holds the customer number as you suggested but the Operator clicking "transfer" does not trigger the call offering from Tapi Events. The Call Offering gets triggered when the operator calls my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Following Kris Vanherck's suggestion, I did a temporary measure to handle the transfers until we figure out a proper solution;

```
     string con="000";
                            while (con.Length ==3 && con.Length >=3)
                            {

                                con = cln.Call.get_CallInfoString(TAPI3Lib.CALLINFO_STRING.CIS_CONNECTEDIDNUMBER);
                            }
```

Silly approach but hey it works. Can't wait to see a more appropriate way to do this. Again thanks Kris for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

You're making it too hard on yourself. You don't need to call Hold manually, the `Transfer` Method does it for you.

When a new call from B comes in (`TAPI_EVENT.TE_CALLNOTIFICATION`), you can take its `ITBasicCallControl` to call `Transfer` on:

```
case TAPI_EVENT.TE_CALLNOTIFICATION:
  ITBasicCallControl incomingCall = callNotification.Call;
  break;
```

The `Transfer` Method takes a pointer to a new created call for consultation, so make sure you create a new call before hand:

```
//In this case address is of type ITAddress and represents the operators address.
ITBasicCallControl consultationCall = address.CreateCall("107", TapiConstants.LINEADDRESSTYPE_PHONENUMBER, TapiConstants.TAPIMEDIATYPE_AUDIO);
```

Now you can call Transfer:

```
incomingCall.Transfer(consultationCall, false);
```

Finally, when the consultation call disconnects, and Alice wants to take the call, use the `Finish` Method to finish transfering:

```
case CALL_STATE.CS_DISCONNECTED:
  ITBasicCallControl consultationCall = (ITBasicCallControl )callStateEvent.Call;
  consultationCall.Finish(FINISH_MODE.FM_ASTRANSFER);
  break;
```

Comment: Yeah that is another approach. Thing is, i may have to call, maybe the person who replies cant take the call that is on hold and i will have to make another consultation call to someone else. So the Disconnected event might make it a bit weird there no? Not sure. I could try it and let you know! Thanks for your time :)

Comment: The `ITCallStateEvent` has a `CALL_STATE_EVENT_CAUSE` property, which will tell you the cause why a disconnect event has been risen.  `CEC_DISCONNECT_NOANSWER` is the one you're looking for, but, depending on your PBX, `CALL_STATE_EVENT_CAUSE` might not be set properly, I think.